# Use desktop-file-install to uninstall?

Tags: .desktop

I installed a desktop file using `desktop-file-install` now I changed my mind and I want to remove it, can I use `desktop-file-edit` to manage the installed desktop files?

I particularly want to use `desktop-file-install` or `desktop-file-edit` Because I want to see if it's possible or not, and I do not want to use `sudo rm /usr/share/applications/eclipse*.desktop` that won't be accepted.